# cannot install hbase 0.94.13 on windows 7x64

Tags: windows, hbase

I am trying to install hbase on windows 7 using cygwin : Here is what I have written in hbase-env.sh:

```
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/jdk
export HBASE_IDENT_STRING=user-PC
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/hbase-0.94.13-bin/lib
```

I have followed all tutorials  without succeeding:After typing bin/start-hbase.sh  this is what i get:

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to /cygdrive/c/hbase-0.94.13/bin/../logs/hbase-user-PC-master-user-PC.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
user@localhost's password:
localhost: Permission denied, please try again.
user@localhost's password:
localhost: starting regionserver, logging to C:\hbase-2.1.3-bin/logs/hbase-user-PC-regionserver-user-PC.out
localhost: cygpath: can't convert empty path
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.
```

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Double check your path and classpath environment variables https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk    AND HBASE_HOME IS SET TO C:\hbase-0.94.13-bin

Comment: That's not what you have listed in your question